# How do I fix input on retroarch?

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to make an emulator machine using retroarch. I've got ubuntu 17.04 installed and I recently installed retroarch; which by default is supposed to use keyboard arrow keys to navigate the menu pre gamepad configuration. Upon launch however, retroarch is unresponsive. It shows the base menu but I can't navigate it at all with any mouse or keyboard. I've tried a variety of buttons and I can't even exit retroarch without restarting the computer because no inputs seem to interact with it. Has anyone else encountered this? Is there some reason it wouldn't recognize my keyboard or is there a way to force it to recognize those keys?

Answer (score 2):

Close Retroarch and delete this file: ~/.config/retroarch/retroarch.cfg

Open Retroarch and, inmediately close it again.

Edit the file ~/.config/retroarch/retroarch.cfg in a text editor, search for the line with this text:

```
video_driver
```

Make the line to look like this:

```
video_driver = "gl"
```

Now, search the line with this text:

```
input_driver
```

Edit the complete line to look like this:

```
input_driver = "sdl2"
```

Save and open Retroarch again.